# how to trigger url changes in single page applications

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a web component in stencil and hosted in angular app. I want to track or trigger the url changes in angular application but routing in angular doesn't trigger native hashchange event on the window.

Is there any way to trigger the url changes from angular app as I want to capture the url-changes in my webcomponent

```
I have tried below code which is written in stencil to listen for url change but its not getting trigger
 @Listen('window:hashchange')
   onListHandle (event) {
     alert('location: ' + document.location + ', state-hash: ' + JSON.stringify(event.state))
   }
   @Listen('window:popstate')
   onpopstate (event) {
     alert('location: ' + document.location + ', state-popstate: ' + JSON.stringify(event.state))
   }
```

Comment: please show us what you've tried

Comment: make sure to add some code samples when you post a question

Comment: In SPA in angular you should use `Router` and `ActivatedRoute` services to trigger and handle url changes.

Answer (score 0):

> HTML5 introduced the history.pushState() and history.replaceState()
>   methods, which allow you to add and modify history entries,
>   respectively. These methods work in conjunction with the
>   window.onpopstate event. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method)

**Example**

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```